# This SQL query is returning nothing when I know the data exists

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql

I am trying to pull information for items to display on the page.  For some reason, the Master Category (masCat.cat_name) is not returning data.  Here is the code for my SQL statement:

```
  strSQL.CommandText = "Select Top 25 tblItem.item_id, tblItem.item_title
     , masCat.cat_name, regCat.cat_name, tblItem.item_lot, tblCosigner.cs_txt_id
     , tblItem.item_status, tblItem.item_photo_status, tblItem.item_pr
     , tblItem.item_premium
  From tblItem
  Left Join tblCosigner On (tblItem.item_cs_txt_id = tblCosigner.cs_txt_id)
  Left Join tblCDR On (tblItem.item_cdr_txt_id = tblCDR.cs_id)
  Left Join tblCat As masCat On (tblItem.item_mcat_id = masCat.cat_id)
  Left Join tblCat As regCat On (tblItem.item_cat_id = regCat.cat_id)
  Where " + sqlQuery + "
  Order By tblItem.item_id;";
  try
  {
      conn.Open();
      using (SqlDataReader itemReader = strSQL.ExecuteReader())
      {
          while (itemReader.Read())
          {
              resultText += "<tr>\n<td>" + itemReader.GetValue(0).ToString() + "</td>\n";
              resultText += "<td>" + itemReader.GetValue(1).ToString() + "</td>\n";
              resultText += "<td>" + itemReader.GetValue(2).ToString() + "</td>\n";
              resultText += "<td>" + itemReader.GetValue(3).ToString() + "</td>\n";
              resultText += "<td>" + itemReader.GetValue(4).ToString() + "</td>\n";
              resultText += "<td>" + itemReader.GetValue(5).ToString() + "</td>\n";
              resultText += "<td>" + itemReader.GetValue(6).ToString() + "</td>\n";
              resultText += "<td>" + itemReader.GetValue(7).ToString() + "</td>\n";
              if (itemReader.GetValue(8).ToString().Length > 0)
              {
                  price = double.Parse(itemReader.GetValue(8).ToString());
              }
              if (itemReader.GetValue(9).ToString().Length > 0)
              {
                  premium = double.Parse(itemReader.GetValue(9).ToString());
              }
              total = price + premium;
              resultText += "<td>" + total.ToString("0.00") + "</td>\n</tr>\n";
          }
          itemReader.Close();
      }
  }
```

I was thinking that my join statement was incorrect for the masCat join, but if I just change tblItem.item_mcat_id to just tblItem.item_cat_id (which is the secondary category, also selected in this same query), it works just fine.  Both are being pulled from the exact same table, but by different associated fields in the relational table.  I am positive tblItem.item_mcat_id is the correct name of the field for the master category id.

Now I am used to using MySQL, and I do know that with SQL you are supposed to do a Group By as well.  But I do not know what I would group by other than tblItem.item_id so that it does not combine rows of data.  So I don't see how that would solve my issue either.  Can anyone see anything wrong with this SQL statement?  Everything returns fine except for the master category.

I got interrupted several times while writing this, so I kind of lost track of my thinking during it, so I hope I gave enough information.  If not, just ask, and I will respond or update my question.  Thanks in advance...

**EDIT**

It's in the comments, but the sqlQuery variable has a default value of "tblItem.item_id > 0".  It works if I add other criteria to it dynamically (not including the master category still).

Also, I must not have stated something right, but I do receive results from this.  I am only missing the master category field (it's returning blank for this one).  The query itself is not failing.

**FIXED**

Whoever created the tables originally made the tblItem.item_mcat_id zero pad...  -.-

Comment: Having properly formatted SQL can help you find potential problems easier.

Comment: What is the value of sqlQuery?

Comment: It seems like this question would be better addressed without considering the c#.

Comment: What's the SQL look like when commandtext is evaluated? Since you're using Dynamic SQL we have no idea what the variable where clause contains which may be where your problem is. (and use parameters, you're opening yourself up to SQL injection.)

Comment: What do you mean "with SQL you are supposed to do a group by as well"?

Comment: @ChrisFarmer, I removed c# tag already :)

Comment: @ChrisFarmer MySQL doesn't require a `GROUP BY` when using an aggregate function, but T-SQL will complain if a column isn't contained in either an aggregate function or the `GROUP BY` clause... but this query doesn't have an aggregate function, and that wouldn't result in no rows, it would result in an exception.

Comment: Is the tblItem.Item_Mcat_ID populated with values in tblCat?  From what I Read, you're getting results from all tables except when you join to tblCat the 2nd time.. this implies to me that the data is missing from one of the two columns.

Comment: I am currently testing this with "sqlQuery" equalling "tblItem.item_id > 0".  But when I populate it, it would look something like "tblItem.item_id > 0 And tblItem.item_mcat_id = 10 And tblItem.item_title like '%the%'" or various other ways.  It does pull data this way as well (except for the master category name), but to just test it, I'm not specifying search criteria.

Comment: @James, remove the C# code, please. You need to resolve the SQL portion, and you don't need all the other clutter to do so. Also, you're missing a huge chunk (the entire `WHERE` clause), which you would have noticed if you removed all the other noise. (And "to just test it, I'm not specifying search criteria" means the query would fail due to a syntax error - a `WHERE ORDER BY`, to be specific.)

Comment: @xQbert No, tblItem.item_mcat_id is the id associated with the table tblCat's entry id's (tblCat.cat_id).  But since the table tblCat holds all categories, whether master categories or sub categories, I had to join the table twice and give it two different aliases.  So if tblItem.item_mcat_id = 10, I'm looking for the name of the category in tblCat where the cat_id = 10.

Comment: @KenWhite The query doesn't fail because by default, it just looks for item id's greater than 0.  I'm just not specifying any dynamic search criteria (from user input).  But I had kept the C# in case I had messed something up with that instead of the actual SQL statement, which is also why I had the C# tag.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer Well I actually had the C# tag in there in case I had something wrong in that code instead, and just didn't realize it.

Comment: @James I understand, but as your query WORKS xpt for the master data isn't being displayed, per your own words. The line that must be having the problem is: Left Join tblCat As masCat On (tblItem.item_mcat_id = masCat.cat_id)  So either one of these columns is either missing data, or doesn't exist in the other table.  IF you had a limit in the where clause, it would error OR show no records, but your getting them back.  So I'm back to the join and invalid data.

Comment: @xQbert That's why I was thinking it was the join as well.  But I know that there is category id's in both tables, and that all field names are correct.  Could there be an issue with my table aliases by chance?

Comment: You know this code has a MASSIVE sql injection vulnerability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the description you've given, I'd have to say that these two columns:

```
tblItem.item_mcat_id = masCat.cat_id
```

Are not the same type or one contains padding where the other does not. You might have to do a cast. Finally MAKE SURE that the item.mcat_id DOES ACTUALLY exist in the cat_id column.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  I am actually certain that the names are correct and that the id's exist in both tables.  However, the padding is a good suggestion.  I will check that right now.

Answer (score 0):

With the code you posted it is impossible to help you directly.

For starters, you need to use Parametrized Queries otherwise you're wise open for SQL Injection attacks and other nastiness.

I suggest you read [Give me parametrized queries or give me death](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) for a overview of why.

That being said, the only way to solve your problem is for you to place the full resulting query string into SQL Management Studio (or use its basic version in VS) and see what the output is. This means you'll need to output the CommandText property while executing the program.

This can be done with [Debug.WriteLine()](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815788). The results will end up in your OUTPUT window by default.

Comment: There must be some misunderstanding.  I get results, just not that one field.  I will have to specify this in my question because everyone seems to think I'm getting nothing back.  But I put the variable criteria in myself after checking user input.  So what they enter isn't added directly into the query string.  I appreciate the tip, though, and do use this in other places.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things...  Does not seem that you are checking to see if sqlQuery is empty string or not.  Also I usually check to see if my data reader has rows before trying to read from it

```
if(itemReader.HasRows) 
{ 
     While(itemReader.Read())
     {

     }
}
```

not sure if those are the problems or not but I would start there.